# Press and get $event

Tags: ionic-framework

I would like to get the $event when I press an image using IONIC 2. It works when I use (click), but it doesn't work when I use (press):

That works:

```
<img [src]="thumb.URL" *ngIf="thumb.URL" (click)="addVisualComment($event)"/>
```

That doesn't work:

```
<img [src]="thumb.URL" *ngIf="thumb.URL" (press)="addVisualComment($event)"/>
```

How can I get $event through the press gesture?

I want to distinguish the click and the press gesture because I use the click for zooming (thanks to imageViewerModule).

Thanks for your help and have a good day.

Comment: you could try using `tap` instead of `click`.. The two gestures are distinguished

Comment: The press is fired but I can't retrieve the e.offsetX instead of with click method I retrieve this information.